# Install visual studio 2015 "setup blocked" with 10 errors

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015

who can help me about **visual studio 2015 install problem** ??? preview windows update error

here is the screenshot of the setup blocking:

[image]

and here are the errors I get for this setup:

```
Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (WindowsBuildNumber < 9600)' evaluates to false.
Condition 'CompatibilityMode = 0' evaluates to false.
Condition 'NOT((VersionNT > v6.1) OR (VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1))' evaluates to false.
Condition '(NOT IsLanguagePack) AND ( CurrentOperation = "Install" ) AND ( FLP_Version > v14.0.22310 )' evaluates to false.
Condition 'RebootPending = 1' evaluates to false.
Condition 'NOT (IEsvcVersionExists) OR (IEsvcVersion < v10.0)' evaluates to false.
Condition '(VersionNT < v6.2) AND ((NetworkAvailable = 0) OR (DisableRootAutoUpdate = 1)) AND NOT ((MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011AuthRootExists) AND (MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010AuthRootExists))' evaluates to false.
Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (KB2919355_amd64_CurrentState <> 112 AND KB2919355_x86_CurrentState <> 112)' evaluates to true.
Condition '(Not UltimateVersion_DetectKey) AND ProfessionalVersion_DetectKey AND (ProfessionalVersion_DetectKey < v14.0.22230) AND (CurrentOperation = "Install")' evaluates to false.
Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (netfxfullredist_43_DetectKey < v4.5.50709)' evaluates to false.
```

can someone suggest a fix to this setup error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your setup is blocked until you install [KB 2919355](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355). You will find two methods to install this update in this link. This would definitely unblock it.

**UPDATE** if these updates are installed successfully, then the problem is because the download package is corrupted, you just need to redownload it and hope it works for you. Even if the package sizes are the same, this should be downloaded again. this could have been caused by interrupted download process.

Comment: i installed that file , but have problem again

Comment: as you see, it says that you can see the log file. what do you have in the log file? please share it here.

Comment: it's to long !!
i put download link , download and see this

Comment: anyway, give us the link, from dropbox, or somewhere else.  the solution lies in that log file.

Comment: have you installed [this update as well](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919442)? if not, this update should be installed first and then the KB 2919355.

Comment: i updated my answer, please read it again, it is because your package is corrupt, please download it again, with reliable internet connection though.

Comment: Ok , i will check this , tanQ

Comment: please accept this answer please. check the tick under the answer counter.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install KB2919442 first before installing KB2919355.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial can help.

Three Simple Steps to Solve the Problem

Step 1:  Before proceeding with the solution, please make sure you are using Windows 8.1 x64 OS;

To find out OS Architecture, Run following command in Command Prompt of Windows (cmd.exe)

C:\Users\sandeep>wmic os get osarchitecture
OSArchitecture
64-bit

Step 2: Download and Install Windows8.1-KB2975061-x64.msu

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=43530

Step 3 : Download and Install Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42335

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42335

Note: Second one is little heavier update and will take longer to download as well install.   So, please have patience.
Installing-Windows-Update

Once both of above updates are installed.  Start Visual Studio 2015 Community Installer once again.  This time Installation completes like a charm.
VisualStudioCommunity-Install

Problem Solved!

Credits:

http://beingzero.in/c-sharp-selenium/visual-studio-2015-installation-troubleshooting