# Visual Studio 2015 install

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to update to Visual Studio Professsional 2015, but it will not load and tells me I need KB 2919355 which is already installed on my PC. Any suggestions? Error is different from previous posted message, like I stated I have the update installed.
Here is the log file:

> Stop Block: This version of Visual Studio requires the April 2014 update to Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 known as !$!go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=403643&clcid=0x409!,!KB 2919355!@!. Please install !$!go.microsoft.com/fwlink? LinkId=403643&clcid=0x409!,!KB 2919355!@! before you install Visual Studio on these operating systems. [3704:1FA8][2015-12-29T05:58:12]i000: MUX: Go to Blocker page. [3704:1FA8][2015-12-29T05:58:12]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [visual studio 2015 "setup blocked" with 10 errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344300/visual-studio-2015-setup-blocked-with-10-errors)

Comment: Here is the log file:  Stop Block: This version of Visual Studio requires the April 2014 update to Windows 8.1 and Windows 

Server 2012 R2 known as !$!http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=403643&clcid=0x409!,!KB 2919355!@!. Please install !$!http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?

LinkId=403643&clcid=0x409!,!KB 2919355!@! before you install Visual Studio on these operating systems.
[3704:1FA8][2015-12-29T05:58:12]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[3704:1FA8][2015-12-29T05:58:12]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0